# Check if number should be C++ float or C++ double using python

Tags: python, c++, precision, narrowing

I am working on a simple C++ code generator created by excel parsing and I will need to distinguish between number type. I can deduce integer size (e.g. `uint_32_t`) using `sys.getsizeof()`
But How can I check if a non-decimal number should be float or a double in order to avoid narrowing?
for each number I know its range, its minimal and maximal value, if it would be of any help.
Thank you very much

Comment: `type_x = (float)(x) == (doube)(x) ? "float" : "double"`

Comment: Most numbers on most computers are non-decimal binary. I think you mean rational number or real number. In any case, make sure you have a working test infrastructure, in order to make the code easier to port to different systems.

Comment: Every floating point value should be `double`, nothing should be `float`, unless you are using between 100% and 200% of the available storage with `double`s

Comment: @Caleth: Sorry, that's a rather outdated idea. Modern CPU's have fixed-bitwidth vector instructions, which means you can process twice as many floats per instruction. E.g. AVX-512 is 16 floats or 8 doubles.

Comment: @MSalters I'd prefer to have all the arithmetic in one precision, rather than a mix. A more nuanced take would be "`float` if everything fits in `float`, otherwise `double`"

Comment: knowing the range, minimal and maximal value isn't enough because you also need to know the precision